# Exponential Fit to Data Points in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to fit an exponential curve of first order (I'm going to make one of second order as well) to some data points in Matlab. I've been trying to use the method that was described in an other question here at StackOverflow but I only get this message: 'Error in ==> fit at 115
    errstr = handleerr('curvefit:fit:xDataMustBeColumnVector', ...'.

This is my code:

```
hold on

X = (1x8-vector containing data);
Y = (1x8-vector containing data);
Error = (1x8-vector containing data);

YError = Y.*Error;

ft = fittype('exp1');
f = fit(X, Y,ft);

errorbar(X, Y, YError, 'squarek','MarkerFaceColor','k')
plot(f,X,Y)
```

I know that 'fit' should return the coefficents of the exponential curve so I'm aware that the last 'plot' is not going to work. Right now I can't even get the coefficents out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1x8 vector is a row vector. A 8x1 vector would be a column vector.  This may seem a trivial distinction, but it would have an effect on the workings of the code, so fit requires size(X,2) to be either 1 or 2 (you can see this by typing edit fit.m at the command line).

Granted, the error you got is a little opaque. R2011b throws (with correct line numbers for iFit and fit):

> X must be a matrix with one or two columns.

Just X', Y' will fix this problem (or adjust the code that produces X and Y to give you column vectors in the first place).